# Changing the value of an input field of type:"time"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-core

This is about a system where users can enter their company open and closing times.

I have 7 fields which are equal to 7 days `<input type="time">`, these are populated with times from a database.

This input has a default display of **--:--** but when you change it to that the value of the field is not adjusted. What I want is the following:
Whenever a user submits the form and a field display consists of **--:--**, I want to change the value of that field to **-1**. Why? Because **-1** means that a company is closed on that day.

How can I achieve this?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please add a code snippet and clarify what you mean with "--.--".

Comment: **"--:--"** is the default value of the input with type of **time**. What I want is if someone has selected **--:--** the value of the input should change to anything. Now if I select the default the value does NOT change.

Comment: _"if someone has selected --:-- the value of the input should change to anything"_ ...ok, but what is the value of "anything"?? It's unclear what you want to change the value to, exactly?

Comment: This is about open and close times of a company. What I do is the following: I get strings which consist of times from a database for example **"09:30"**. These I use to populate those time input fields with. A company can also be closed so I want to be able to send **-1** through those time input fields when I have the default value selected. Because **-1** is equal to "closed" in my system. I hope this clears up things.

Comment: -1 is not really a time, though, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to put that in a time field. And in fact you simply _can't_ put that into a HTML time field. Better to leave it as-is. In your controller, if you get that value posted, you can convert it to -1 there.

Comment: True but the field is hooked up to a string, so it actually isn't a time, I just want force the user input to what a time should be like formatted in my system and thats like this. `hh:mm` where `h = hour` and `m = minute`. And it looks a bit neater than just a text field.

Comment: The underlying field might not be a time (although hopefully it is in your database, at least!!), but a HTML time field cannot display -1, because it can only display valid times, and -1 isn't a valid time. P.S. You also said `I just want force the user input to what a time should be like formatted in my system and thats like this. hh:mm where h = hour and m = minute` ...that's all fine, no issues with that. But that has nothing to do with displaying -1, which is what you said was the problem

Comment: @ADyson I don't wan to display **-1** I simply want to display **--:--** while the value is **-1**. So when I post the form while I have **--:--** selected it will post **-1**.

Comment: Ok. That's not how you described it before. But you can't make it post -1, because -1 isn't there. Like I said before, get your controller to detect the incoming empty time value and convert it to -1. But really really really you should **not** be storing the time in your database in such a way that you could also put -1 in that field. You should use some sort of `time` or `datetime` type, depending on your database engine. And it should be NULL, if there is no value. By using these -1s you're just making your life more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Link :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Minimal-Date-Time-Input-Mask-Validation-Plugin-For-jQuery.html

alex-date-time.js is a lightweight and convenient jQuery input mask plugin which automatically formats and validates date & time inputs in "DD/MM/YYYY" and "HH:MM" formats.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of the problem is not very clear but if you want to display a value from database you can disable the input field and display a value in it with the `value=`

Here an example:

```
<form>
  <input type="time" name="time" value="09:30" disabled><br>
</form>
```

Comment: If `<input type="time">` has no value it will display **--:--**. But if I load data from the database to populate that inputfield it has a value let's say `08:30` . Basically what the problem is is that there seems to be no way to have that inputfield have no value or null if you will while displayin **--:--**. So what I want is if the default (**--:--**)  is displaying, the value should be null or -1. Now it's what I loaded from the database, even after I changed the time in the field.

Answer (score -2):

The explanation of the problem is not very clear but if you want to display a value from database you can disable the input field and display a value in it with the value=

Here an example:

Comment: Your example is missing!